# Multiple TextToSpeech instances in Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

We have an Android app that will have a service occasionally performing TTS operations in the background to a file (calling synthesizeToFile) and an Activity performing TTS operations for immediate output (calling speak).  My plan was to create two separate instances of TextToSpeech.  Each instance calls setOnUtteranceCompletedListener to listen for utterance complete.

I assumed each instance would operate independently, so that neither instance would interrupt the other.  However, it appears that setOnUtteranceCompletedListener does not behave as expected.  Only one of the instances will ever receive callbacks, depending on the order that the service and activity start up.

Is it invalid to have two instances of TextToSpeech in a single process?  Do you only get one TTS engine per process and therefore all TTS action within the process must share the engine.

Comment: Why don't you bind to the service and have the activity sent messages to the service to speak?

Answer (score -1):

It is valid to create multiple instances of TTS in a single process. (I have done this successfully)
Each instance is independent of other instance.

Important thing is to keep track of the instances, because you need to stop/shutdown the tts after use from every instance.